# How to change Add button to remove after adding in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

want to show only add button in first row ,
when i click add ,add new row and change or hide add button to remove.
continuously same. and first row should not remove and show add button

```
div ng-app="ReceiptsApp">
    <div ng-controller="ReceiptsController">
        <table class="tableData">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in rvm">
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="c" style="width:150px;height:22px;" ng-options="c.name for c in sample">
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" lass="input-large" ng-model="c.Address" name="Address" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" ng-model="c.Mobile" name="Mobile" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="addRow($index,c)">Add</button>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteRow($index)">Remove</button>

                </td>


            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var ReceiptsApp = angular.module('ReceiptsApp', []);

ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.sample = [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'Bhanu',
        Address: 'Moosapet',
        Mobile: '9246100100'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Madhu',
        Address: 'Uppal',
        Mobile: '9000330653'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Geetha',
        Address: 'Sanath Nagar',
        Mobile: '9912340519'
    }];
    $scope.rvm = [{}];
    $scope.addRow = function (index, c) {
        if ($scope.rvm.length == (index + 1)) {
            $scope.rvm.push({
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.deleteRow = function ($index) {
$scope.rvm.splice($index, 1);
}


});
```

i have posted code here

https://jsbin.com/yamobarapo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cheap & fast trick would be to make the Add button show only for the last element of `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<td ng-if="$last">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="addRow($index,c)">Add</button>            
</td>
<td ng-if="!$last">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteRow($index)">Remove</button>          
</td>
```

I have also updated your [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wemicegeka/1/edit?html,js,output) to see it in action.